# I have my 12 word seed

Tags: wallet, seed

I put my Bitcoin into a wallet some time ago, kept the 12 words but do not remember which wallet I used.
Now I understand that all that matters is that I have my 12 words but I am having difficulty (due to lack of knowledge) in using these words to regain my coins.
Any help please?
Many Thanks
Dave

Comment: Do you know which wallet you were using? You need to know which derivation path was being used.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you download and install electrum. Then run and select "standard wallet" in the first step > "I already have a seed" > then enter your seed words. If your seed is a valid electrum seed it should let you proceed to the next step. If it is not then click on options and check bip39. Then see what message is displayed next to the options button. If it says "bip39 checksum ok" you can proceed to the next step where you choose the legacy p2pkh option because that is the most likely address type. Then follow on-screen instructions for the rest.

If the above doesn't work then I suggest you look at your filesystem to learn what wallets you installed in the past. Also look at your email archives in case you used a blockchain.info wallet. Make a post about what you find on the bitcoin talk forum technical support subforum or /r/bitcoinbeginners subreddit and post a link the comments so we can help you further.

Comment: Abdussamad, that seems to have worked in that after following your instructions Electrum shows a default_ wallet (standard) with a balance in it measured in mBTC. I assume I have found my Bitcoins and can now sell them via the SEND function. Well done!

Comment: @DaveB glad I could help. You may want to mark my answer as the solution to your query.